# Redis data replication

Tags: redis

I am trying to do data replication using redis server and jedis client. What I am asking may be completely wrong. I just started exploring the things today.

I have configured 2 laptops in my network.
Config on node1 is default the config.

### Config on node2:

updated redis.conf file to have this line:

```
slaveof <node1 ip> <port on which redis server is running>
```

I have a stand-alone java program on both of the nodes.

Case 1:
I did `jedis.set("key1", "value1");` from node1 (master). I am able to retrieve key-value from node2.

Case 2:
I did `jedis.set("key2", "value2");` from node2 (slave). But I'm not able to see that replicated on the master node.

Question is, is it expected behavior? My requirement is to keep the data in sync on all the nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. Writes to the master will propagate to the slave(s), writes to the slave(s) will *not* propagate to the master. If you want to use Redis, you will have to write to the master and read from the slave(s). See [Redis replication documentation](http://redis.io/topics/replication).